# Facebook Tracking Pixel On a Button Event

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm trying to set up a facebook tracking pixel on my website. I need the pixel to be triggered on the submission of a contact form. My contact form does not redirect to a new page on submission, so i need to place the pixel to "track event on in-line action".

This is the snippet facebook have given me:

```
<button id="submitButton">Generate lead</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#$submitButton').click(function() {
      insert_event_code_here;
      ...
</script>
```

And this is my current button Script:

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="contactForm">
    <!-- my form fields -->
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right control-submit">Send!</button>
    </div>
```

How do i splice these two bits of code together to make a working facebook pixel triggered when the user clicks the send message button?

Also, where the facebook code says "`insert_event_code_here;`" what is this?

Many thanks everyone!

Comment: _“Also, where the facebook code says "insert_event_code_here;" what is this?”_ - well the code that performs the actual pixel call to track the event …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to track the click on the button you can trigger an event with something like the sample code at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api/pixel#inpageevents

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="contactForm">

<!-- my form fields -->

<div class="col-md-12">

<button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right control-submit" onclick="fbq('track', 'Purchase');">Send!</button>

</div>
```

Comment: You are a star! Thanks

Comment: But how do you add the lately needed parameters `currency` and `value` here?

Comment: fbq('track', 'Purchase', {currency: 'USD', value: 12})